# Matlab Weka Interface AdaBoost Issues: Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: matlab, weka, adaboost

I'm doing some cross-validation using a Matlab Weka Interface that I got from file exchange. My loop structure seems to work fine for Weka's Logistic classifier. However, when I try to do the exact same thing for AdaBoostM1, it throws the following error:

```
??? Java exception occurred: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Error in ==> wekaClassify at 24 classProbs(t+1,:) = (classifier.distributionForInstance(testData.instance(t)))';

Error in ==> classifier_search at 225 [pred ~] = wekaClassify(matlab2weka('instance', featurelabels, tester), classifier);
```

I have determined through some testing that this only occurs when the number of instances in the training set is greater than the number of instances in the test set. I am sure you can see why that is a problem for me, since in most situations the training set is greater than the test set in size.

Is there something different about how I should format my inputs when using Adaboost rather than Logistic? Any information you can give regarding this problem would be so helpful.

I downloaded this code from this page: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21204-matlab-weka-interface

Emails bounce from the account of the guy who made it, and he doesn't seem to respond to comments on the page - I'm hoping that maybe someone here has used this.

EDIT: Here is the code that I use to train and test the classifier:

```
classifier = trainWekaClassifier(matlab2weka('training', featurelabels, train), 'meta.AdaBoostM1', { strcat('-P 100 -S 1 -I ', num2str(r), '-W weka.classifiers.trees.DecisionStump')});
[pred ~] = wekaClassify(matlab2weka('instance', featurelabels, tester), classifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this combination of software, so I can only take a guess at what could cause this.

Are your training/testing data matrices the right way round? They should be N-by-D (N instances, D features).

If you were passing in a D-by-N training matrix and a D-by-M testing matrix, then I would expect it to work only when M < N - which is what you describe - and even then, it wouldn't give a meaningful result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, the matrices are correctly oriented. I used the exact same code, but with a different classifier, in another program and it works there. Additionally, just to be sure, I tried transposing the matrices and that caused it to break because the labels were not of type string.

Comment: can you show the code that you use to train and test your classifier?

Comment: I apologize for my slow response - I didn't receive notification of your comment. I've made the edit you've requested in my post. Thank you so much!